# How do I check if there are different captured characters between two same characters?

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if a string has the same start and end character and all characters in between are *different* from the start and end character.

Examples:

- `"abcda"` should **pass**, because it starts and ends with `a`, and has only non-`a`s in the middle,
- `"abada"` should **fail**, because it not only has `a` at the start and end, but also *in the middle*,
- `"bcdefb"` should **pass** — see the first example.

I tried to do it by `(.)(?!.*\1)\1`, but it failed because there is no length limit, negated end of the string either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```java
^(.)(?:(?!\1).)*\1$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dGXdBb/1). Add `(?s)` at the start if your string can contain line break chars. Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.)` - Group 1: any one char
- `(?:(?!\1).)*` - any one char that is not equal to the char captured in Group 1, zero or more times
- `\1` - backreference to the Group 1 value, same char as in the group is required here
- `$` - end of string.

In Java, with `String#matches()`, you may omit the anchors:

```java
string.matches("(.)(?:(?!\\1).)*\\1")
```